# Response Parsed Body Dynamic Value Arrays

Tags: paw-app

This may end up falling into the feature request category, but I can't seem to find a method to parse all of the values of a returned array. I'm working with XML returns (sigh), but I suspect that this is equally application to JSON.

I'd like to be able to insert a variable in the string that represents the array tag at a given position; For example :

```
QueryResultRecords.VAppTemplateRecord.[].name
```

Such that the resulting values are applied to all of the entries in an array of unknown length. Also, if it is possible to apply this to the results pane (especially important with verbose XML) to extract just the list of the useful values.

Right now, I'm hard coding:

```
QueryResultRecords.VAppTemplateRecord.1.name
QueryResultRecords.VAppTemplateRecord.2.name
QueryResultRecords.VAppTemplateRecord.3.name
...
```

into multiple X-Code Parsed Reponse blocks which sort of does the job, but isn't very elegant :-)

Comment: Sorry @Erik for the late answer here. We're implementing filtering for JSON responses, and it will include the `*` key to match all array keys, not yet scheduled for XML though... You're right, we should handle the star key to the extracting (request/response parsed body) as well.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri No worries - I can wait :-) Like I said, more of a feature request than a bug.